# Clean URLs with multiple variables failing if more than required variables are provided

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I've started delving into clean URLs for user pages, taking most of my inspiration from Stack Overflows way of doing it. A user can enter just the user id of the user they wish to view, which will then redirect them to the correct URL, including the display name. For example, if I have account with id 1, visiting `users/1` will redirect to `users/1/JosephDuffy`, assuming my display name is `JospehDuffy`. From here, extra actions can be performed, such as editing yourself, so `users/1/JosephDuffy/edit` would edit user 1. `users/1/username/edit` would also redirect to `users/1/JosephDuffy/edit`. All the above example work in a perfect world, but it can be easily broken.
Users can perform actions on others, such as `users/2/Player2/befriend`. Obviously, you do not want to befriend yourself, so `users/1/JospehDuffy/befriend` doesn't do anything. However, entering a URL such as `users/1/1/1/1/JosephDuffy/befriend` seems to trigger the action as `befriend`, the display name as `JosephDuffy` and the user id as `1/1/1/1`. I'm guessing that this is just how mod_rewrite works, but it seems to be throwing me some curve balls.
For now, I'm using `intval()` on the user id, which seems to work but is less than ideal; I am still left with multiple URLs that serve the same information, and although I can't find any other "holes", there might still be some. I'm not sure where the problem lies, so I'll post my .htaccess and the PHP script.
.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite /users to provide the script with the GET variables it requires to function properly, whilst having clean URLs
# 3 variables were provided
RewriteRule ^users/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/$ users.php?userid=$1&displayname=$2&action=$3
RewriteRule ^users/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/([^.]+)$ users.php?userid=$1&displayname=$2&action=$3

# 2 variables were provided
RewriteRule ^users/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/$ users.php?userid=$1&displayname=$2
RewriteRule ^users/([^.]+)/([^.]+)$ users.php?userid=$1&displayname=$2

#1 variable was provided
RewriteRule ^users/([^.]+)/$ users.php?userid=$1
RewriteRule ^users/([^.]+)$ users.php?userid=$1
```

I think that it would also be better if I used `[R=301,L]`, or something similar at some stage in this, but I'm unsure where, or why really.
users.php (some parts are simplified, almost to psudocode, to make it easier to understand)

```
if (isset($_GET['userid'])) {
    $profileUserid = intval($_GET['userid']);
} else {
    $profileUserid = 0;
}
if (isset($_GET['displayname'])){
    $profileDisplayName = $_GET['displayname'];
} else {
    $profileDisplayName = '';
}
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
} else {
    $action = false;
}
$actualDisplayName = GetDisplayNameFromDBWhereid($profileUserid);
if ($actualDisplayName != $profileDisplayName) {
        header('Location: /users/' . $profileUserid . '/' . $actualDisplayName . '/' . $action);
        exit;
    } else if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -1) != '/') {
        // There is no trailing slash, so add it
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '/');
        exit;
    }
    if ($currentUsersid == $profileUserid) {
        // Player is viewing themselves
        if ($action == 'edit') {
            echo 'Editing your profile';
        } else {
            // User viewing self, but not editing
            echo '<a href="edit">Edit your profile</a><br>';
        }
    } else {
        if ($action) {
            // Interact with the user whos profile is being viewed
        } else {
        }
    }
```

Without using `intval($_GET['userid'])`, when I enter `users/1/1/1/1/JosephDuffy/action`, it executes `action` as if I where a different user, whilst `1/JosephDuffy/action` shows the "Edit your profile" link, ignoring the action because is does not equal "edit".
Hopefully this is something silly (I'm guessing it's the fault of my poorly written RewriteRules), but never-the-less, thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it works that way?**

Regexps are greedy, they try to fit as much as possible to your regular expression, and thus your `users/1/1/1/1/JosephDuffy/befriend` fits well in pattern `users/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/([^.]+)`. TBH I dont know why `[^.]+` seems to be same as `.+` notation, that makes me wonder most, but ...

---

**How to fix**

If you want to fix that so that it only fits to `users/1/JosephDuffy/befriend` you need to put regexp pattern as

```
^users/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ users.php?userid=$1&displayname=$2&action=$3
```

And change all rest rewrites respectively. Note `([^/]+)` notation there, which means all characters until we find `/`.

---

**and what I would do**

As said that, I still would consider accepting "any kind of URL" and then would do parsing in the PHP end (with `preg_split`). So URL rewrite would be very simple:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ users.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then in code I would

```
$paramsAndValues = preg_split('#/#',$_GET['url']);
```

on it's simpliest, but of course you check if `$_GET['url']` exists and all that.

Comment: For now, the "How to fix" solution works, I guess I've still got a bit to learn about regular expressions! However, I do like the idea of your solution (I did almost do a similar solution previously), so I will look into that in the near future. Thanks!